# how to remove null values in string in java?

Tags: java, regex, string

here is my codings:

```
List<String> Rolelist1=new ArrayList<String>();
StringBuilder b=new StringBuilder();
for(String text1:Rolelist1) {
    b.append(text1).append(",");
}

Roletext1=b.toString().replaceAll(",$", "");
```

I want to convert a list into a string.
for example

```
Rolelist=[A,B,C,B] into string Roletext1=A,B,C,D
```

it works. when my list is empty i will add elements again convert into string it shows `Roletext1=,E,f,g,h.` how can i get the output as E,F,G,h.pls help me

Comment: How Rolelist=[A,B,C,B] is converted to  Roletext1=A,B,C,D

Answer (score 1):

I see two approaches:

```
for(String text1:Rolelist1)
{
   if(text1==null || text1.isEmpty()){
     continue;
   }
   b.append(text1).append(",");
 }
```

or

```
b.toString().replaceAll("^,", "").replaceAll(",,", ",").replaceAll(",$", "");
```

Comment: You're welcome. If this has been the comment that helped you it is good to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

To create the CVS, I just use the `toString()` from List:

```
String cvs = list.toString().replaceAll("[\\[\\] ]", "");
```

It's just one line of code and will work every time.

The `replaceAll()` removes all square brackets and spaces. You may want to leave the spaces (which appear after commas).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
    for (String text1 : Rolelist1) {
        if (text1 != null) {
            b.append(text1).append(",");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> Rolelist1=new ArrayList<String>();
StringBuilder b=new StringBuilder();
      for(String text1:Rolelist1){
              if(text1!=null){
                  b.append(text1).append(",");
              }    
}
Roletext1=b.toString().replaceAll(",$", "");
```

Comment: Why would you do such a thing?